# Is "burnt" being used as an adjective or verb in the second sentence?

Tags: word-choice

In US English, if burnt is the adjective form and burned the verb form, is it grammatically correct to use "burnt" in the second sentence?

> She burned herself while cooking. However, she felt a lot less **burnt/burned** after a letter arrived about a prize she'd won.

I'm trying to understand here whether the second sentence is using "burnt" as an adjective or verb form. Often we say "burnt toast," where "burnt" is the adjective form. Is it the same here?

Comment: Pick one and stick with it, otherwise you sound like you can't make up your mind.

Comment: "If burnt is the adjective form and burned is the verb form" where did you read that? In both AmE and BrE,  you can use both as the  simple past and the past participle. There is a dictionary entry for burnt as an adjective, but you can also use the past participle as an adjective. adjective.https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/burn

Comment: There are no hard-and-fast rules on which to use, only tendencies that vary in different areas of the world. You may find [this article](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/burned-versus-burnt) helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In US English, if burnt is the adjective form and burned the verb
>   form, is it grammatically correct to use "burnt" in the second
>   sentence?

There is no connection.  As per the [verb table for burn](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/burn.html), it is grammatically correct to use either burned or burnt, regardless of having used burnt as an adjective.

> She burned herself while cooking. However, she felt a lot less
>   burnt/burned after a letter arrived about a prize she'd won.

[Burn](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/burnt) can be referred to in the past as either burnt or burned.  Both are correct.  I would offer the following guidelines:

- Burnt - can be used as the participle of burn, I burnt myself.  Can also be used as an adjective, "burnt toast".  Subjectively in every day english, burnt will commonly used in a sentence with finality.  Often phrases like "burnt toast" will be used to suggest that it is burnt, this has happened and that's the end of it (the end of the toast)
- Burned - can also be used as the participle of burn, I burned myself. This cannot be used as an adjective or to describe a noun.  In every day english this would be used more commonly in the verb sense because it follows other participle structures (I bruised myself, I rewarded myself) and it's a softer way of talking.  If I say I burnt myself, I think of toast.

> However, she felt a lot less burnt/burned after a letter arrived about a 
>   prize she'd won.

Whilst technically accurate, I probably wouldn't phrase a sentence like this.  If I apply degree to burned it would be the depth of the burn, 3rd degree burns being serious.  It's a state of health, you can't really "feel less burned", it's like saying that your broken leg "feels less broken".  It's either broken or it is not.

I would probably say "However, she felt better after a letter arrived" or "the pain subsided after the letter arrived" or "she forgot about the burn after the letter arrived"